# Perform some check on an array of objects & if even 1 of the conditions matches , stop the bulk request

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of objects of 1000 elements where each object has below properties :
**name, entity, type, mid, low, high**. I have to perform below checks on the whole array[{},{},..]:

(NOTE : **type** can either be '**static**' or '**dynamic**')

if(**type === 'static'**)  ---> then check if(**mid || high || low**) is not-empty or negative  ----> only then do the bulk request.

if(**type === 'dynamic'**)  ---> then pass

Example - If I have 800 elements & even 1 of the elements has a **type = 'static'** && any of **high, mid or low** is negative or empty  , then the whole 800 elements should not be sent to backend at all & instead show a message to the user to correct that 1 element data.

I tried many logic, nothing works, below is what I tried latest (used array.some()) :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Button varieties
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'button-types-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-types-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-types-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonTypesExample implements OnInit {

   data = [
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#acre-access-reviews-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#acre-access-reviews-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "static",
      mid: "-1",
      low: "-3",
      high: "",
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#alphasi500-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#alphasi500-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#ams-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#ams-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#analytics-services-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#analytics-services-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#appsec-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#appsec-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#astroupgrademanager-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#astroupgrademanager-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#avo-indoor-maps-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#avo-indoor-maps-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    },
    {
      name: "alpha.keyword#aware-streaming-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      entity: "alpha.keyword#aware-streaming-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg",
      type: "dynamic",
      mid: "",
      low: "",
      high: ""
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exists(this.data);
  }

  exists(array: any[]) {
    let DO_BULK_INSERT = array.some(element => {
      if (
        element["type"] === "static" &&
        (element["mid"] === "" ||
          element["low"] === "" ||
          element["high"] === "" ||
          element["mid"] < 0 ||
          element["low"] < 0 ||
          element["high"] < 0)
      ) {
        console.log("element = ", element);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });

    console.log("DO_BULK_INSERT = ", DO_BULK_INSERT);
    if (DO_BULK_INSERT) {
      console.log("DO_BULK_INSERT");
    } else {
      console.log("DO NOT DO BULK_INSERT");
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const datas = [{ name: "alpha.keyword#acre-access-reviews-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg", entity: "alpha.keyword#acre-access-reviews-dev|cpu.usage.limit.pct#avg", type: "static", mid: "1", low: "3", high: "2", }];

const mustSend = datas.every( ({type, high, mid, low }) => type !== 'static' || ( parseInt(high) >= 0 && parseInt(mid) >= 0 && parseInt(low) >= 0 ) );

console.log("Must send?", mustSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, `DO_BULK_INSERT` will be true even if one of the elements pass the condition. Below should work for you.

```
exists(array: any[]) {
    let STOP_BULK_INSERT = array.some(element => {
      if (
        element["type"] === "static" &&
        (element["mid"] === "" ||
          element["low"] === "" ||
          element["high"] === "" ||
          element["mid"] < 0 ||
          element["low"] < 0 ||
          element["high"] < 0)
      ) {
        console.log("element = ", element);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });

    console.log("STOP_BULK_INSERT = ", STOP_BULK_INSERT);
    if (STOP_BULK_INSERT) {
      console.log("STOP BULK INSERT");
    } else {
      console.log("DO NOT STOP_BULK_INSERT");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you reversed the conditions. My requirement is If type = static then only check among high, mind & low if any 1 of them also is < 0 or empty string, then fail the BULK_INSERT

Comment: Yes, so stop (or fail) bulk insert if type=static AND high/mid/low is empty or negative. Array.some() returns true if the underlying condition is true for any of the elements. So your condition should return true when you find a faulty element. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems working, I know the problem, you expect `exists` to return something, but it returns undefined, you've not returned anything from `exists`, you should be returning `DO_BULK_INSERT` to see your solution working.

Let's talk about about how you've handled it when it comes to readability and type checking

Let's agree that there's a type checking error here, We are checking if an element is negative (number) or empty (string). This in terms of TS should be fixed, however, if not, it should work (JavaScript after all)

I'd do smth like

```
function exists(array) {
  function isNegative(x) {
    return x >= 0;
  }

  function isEmptyString(x) {
    return x === '';
  }

  return array.some(element => {
    if (element.type === 'static') {
      return [element.low, element.mid, element.high].some(prop =>
        typeof prop === 'string' ? isEmptyString(prop) : isNegative(prop)
      );
    }
    else {
      return "WHATEVER"
    }
  });
}
```

Anyway, your code is fine, it just returns nothing.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1sxku-3a19p5?file=src/app/button-types-example.ts

Below is what I did

```
dataProcessing(data: any) {
    let DO_BULK_INSERT: boolean = false;
    let BAD_KPI_DATA = [];

    BAD_KPI_DATA = this.filterBadKPI(data);

    if (BAD_KPI_DATA.length > 0) {
      DO_BULK_INSERT = false;
      console.log("DO_NOT_BULK_INSERT = ", DO_BULK_INSERT);
    } else {
      DO_BULK_INSERT = true;
      console.log("DO_BULK_INSERT = ", DO_BULK_INSERT);
    }
  }

  filterBadKPI(array: any[]) {
    let filteredArray = array.filter(this.every);
    console.log("filteredArray = ", filteredArray);
    return filteredArray;
  }

  every(element: any) {
    return (
      element["type"] === "static" &&
      (element["mid"] === "" ||
        element["low"] === "" ||
        element["high"] === "" ||
        parseFloat(element["mid"]) < 0 ||
        parseFloat(element["low"]) < 0 ||
        parseFloat(element["high"]) < 0)
    );
  }
```